# Distillation of free fatty acid from soya acid oil

Tags: organic-chemistry, distillation

I have soya acid oil with FFA percentage of about 40. After degumming and glycerolysis I am able to bring down the FFA percentage to 5. It does go down to about 2 percentage but it takes an enormous amount of time.

At this stage I want to distill the oil and extract two fractions, first being FFA and other being TGs.

Assuming this would also improve the color of the oil and will settle pigment and unsaponifiables as pitch in the distillation flask.

I have following available:

1. Distillation flask 1 litre
2. Packed column 12 inches (ratchet rings)
3. Thermometer head along with thermometer.
4. Condenser Collection flask
   with vaccum adaptor
5. Vaccum pump
6. Heating mantle with temperature dial
   but no visual temperature display.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: If I understand you post correctly. you want to distill TGs too. Such a distillation may be a challenge even for vacuum distillation, having much lover vapor tension than FFAs.

Comment: You do not say what is the purpose of the product.

Comment: To use it as feedstock for FAME

Comment: To readers, FAME =  Fatty Acid Methyl Esters // Avoid using unexplained less common abbreviations. Even if many readers may not be familiar with the topic and topic specific abbreviations, they may still be expert in topics you ask about or you need to know more about.  Better if 1 writer explains them than if many readers have to find their meaning.

Comment: Will take care of it next time. Thank you.

Comment: What is the vapor pressure and at what temperature does decomposition become significant? Note that the longer you heat the mix, the more time it has to degrade.

Comment: Distill the methyl esters.